# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python-2.7

I don't know what's going on, it worked before.
It had never happened to me.
someone help, i'm lost.

error line:

```
        result = p0 + (EMA - d0) / (d1 - d0) * (p1 - p0) if p0 != 100.0 or p1 != 100.0 else 100.0
```

i try this:

```
        if p0 != 100.0 or p1 != 100.0:
            result = p0 + (EMA - d0) / (d1 - d0) * (p1 - p0)
        else:
            result = 100.0
```

code:

```
    def requestCurData(self, damageRating, movingAvgDamage):
        self.values = config.values[self.check_player_thread()][self.name]
        if len(self.values) == 4:
            tm = datetime.datetime.toordinal(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) - 1
            self.values.extend([tm, tm])
            config.values[self.check_player_thread()][self.name] = self.values
        if movingAvgDamage not in self.values or datetime.datetime.toordinal(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) >= self.values[5] + 1:
            p0 = self.values[2]
            d0 = self.values[3]
            t0 = self.values[5]
            p1 = damageRating
            d1 = movingAvgDamage
            t1 = datetime.datetime.toordinal(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
            self.values = [p0, d0, p1, d1, t0, t1]
            config.values[self.check_player_thread()][self.name] = self.values
        if self.values[0] == self.values[2] and self.values[1] == self.values[3]:
            self.values[3] += 10
            self.values[5] = datetime.datetime.toordinal(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
            config.values[self.check_player_thread()][self.name] = self.values
        EDn = self.battleDamage + max(self.RADIO_ASSIST, self.TRACK_ASSIST, self.STUN_ASSIST)
        k = 0.0198019801980198022206547392443098942749202251434326171875  # 2 / (100.0 + 1)
        EMA = k * EDn + (1 - k) * self.movingAvgDamage
        p0, d0, p1, d1, t0, t1 = self.values
        result = p0 + (EMA - d0) / (d1 - d0) * (p1 - p0) if p0 != 100.0 or p1 != 100.0 else 100.0
        nextMark = round(min(100.0, result), 2) if result > 0 else 0.0
        self.initiated = self.values[1] and not nextMark >= self.damageRating and not self.damageRating - nextMark > 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is not clear, but I suppose you might be trying to divide a float by an integer, and Python doesn't like that. Try:

```
result = p0 + (EMA - d0) / float( (d1 - d0) * (p1 - p0) ) if p0 != 100.0 or p1 != 100.0 else 100.0
```

If this didn't work, then may be you are trying to divide by zero, which is not possible, so wrap the calculation inside a try-catch block:

```
try:
   result = p0 + (EMA - d0) / (d1 - d0) * (p1 - p0) if p0 != 100.0 or p1 != 100.0 else 100.0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    result = "some default value"
```

Comment: ```if p0 != 100.0 or p1 != 100.0:
            result = p0 + (EMA - d0) / (d1 - d0) * (p1 - p0)
        else:
            result = 100.0```